# Create Akka actor synchronously

Tags: java, scala, akka

I'm creating an actor using `ActorSystem.actorOf(property, bla)`. The problem is that since by default Akka creates actors asynchronously, I'm having a race condition.

Is there any way to create an actor in Akka synchronously?

Comment: The `actorOf` returns a new `ActorRef` immediately. Could you explain in more detail where the race condition arises?

Comment: Yes return an ActorRef, but internally the creation of the actor it's not yet ready. So when I try to consume that actor it´s failing.

Comment: Can you prove that by a code example?

Comment: The idea is that you shouldn't care whether it's ready or not. If you use the `ActorRef` to send messages to it, those messages will be buffered until the new actor is ready to process them. I'd like to see a piece of code where this leads to a race condition (and that is not one of the usual gotchas, e.g. it shouldn't use shared mutable state to communicate with the new actor bypassing the message passing system).

Comment: Trying to add an example but it´s hard since they are typed actors. I´ll try to provide an example reproducing the issue

Answer (score 2):

In the simplest use case, you can simply adopt this pattern:

1. In the `preStart` of your actor, you initialize a long running asynchronous task
2. Upon its completion you send a message to self with the result of the long running task
3. When handling this result, you initialize the state of the actor.

You also need a Subscribe message: when the actor receives checks its state, if it is initialized it answer immediately, if not append the sender to a list of subscribers. When handling the result of initialization (3) you also notify all the subscribers.

```
trait ExpensiveThing
import MyActor._
class MyActor extends Actor {

  var expensiveThing : ExpensiveThing = null
  var initializationListeners:List[ActorRef] = List.empty


  def initializeExpensiveThing() : Future[ExpensiveThing]  = ???

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    initializeExpensiveThing onSuccess  {
      case s => self ! InitializationDone(s)
    }

  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case InitializationDone(s) =>
      expensiveThing = s
      initializationListeners.foreach{ s => s ! Initialized }
    case SubscribeInitialization =>
      if(expensiveThing != null){
        sender ! Initialized
      }
      else {
        initializationListeners = sender() +: initializationListeners
      }

  }


}

object MyActor{
  case class InitializationDone(s:ExpensiveThing)

  case object SubscribeInitialization

  case object Initialized


}
object MyProgram {
  def doSomething(actorSystem:ActorSystem)  = {
    val actor = actorSystem.actorOf(Props(new MyActor))
    import akka.pattern.ask
    implicit val inizializationTimeout = new Timeout(100,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    Await.result(actor ? SubscribeInitialization,Duration.Inf)
  }
}
```

Notes:

1. I strongly discourage you from doing Await.result, you should simply flatMap on the future that will be returned when you use the ask pattern
2. More complex lifecycle should be handled using context.become or the FSM abstraction that Akka offers.

Comment: I saw that pattern in some blogs, the problem is that those actors are typed actors, and are created dynamically in our framework by our consumers. And force them to implement a method to invoke looks horrible.  Any trick how to do this example with typed actors

Comment: How would you expect to implement lifecycle listening in message passing driven framework like an actor system? Using message passing I guess...

Comment: So Sorry I dont understand what you mean

Comment: How would you like the API to listen for the initialization of an actor to be?

Comment: Expected that the creation could return a future and this one is resolved once the preStart it´s invoked.

Comment: A future of what type?

Comment: future of Object? Apache Camel it has a way to tell you in a callback when an actor consumer it´s created

Comment: Camel give you this feature // get a future reference to the activation of the endpoint of the Consumer Actor
val activationFuture = camel.activationFutureFor(actorRef)(
  timeout = 10 seconds,
  executor = system.dispatcher)

Comment: That is the activation of the Camel processor, which has nothing to do with the initialization of the actor inside the processor. https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/009214ae07708e8144a279e71d06c4a504907e31/akka-camel/src/main/scala/akka/camel/internal/CamelSupervisor.scala. It is important to understand that such a feature is not possible "by design" with actor system: there is no way Camel or any library can "know" the internal state of the actor (initialized or not). Imagine the actor takes 10 minutes to initialize, how would Camel now?